# App Engine "Free Trial" vs "Free Quota"

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, quota, trial

I am confused...  Probably because I am not very smart.

As I understand it:
1. Free Trial gives certain allowance(300 USD) to be used up in 60 days.
2. Free Quota gives daily allowance of free usage to (all?) app engine resources.

Did I understand these two things correctly?  What is the relationship between these?  Is free quota still being offered?  Are there dependencies between these two(if I sign up for free trial, would I lose free quota after the trial ends in 60 days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you got them right. They aren't really related.

The free quotas are still offered. They don't expire and they apply regardless if the app is in the free trial or not. They may get revised now and then, though. From [Billable limits and safety limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas):

> - Free quotas: Every application gets an amount of each resource for free. Free quotas can only be exceeded by paid applications, up to the
>     application's spending limit or the safety limit, whichever applies
>     first.

The free trial has a limited lifespan and simply covers the billed costs of the paid apps (during that limited lifetime) up to that 300 USD amount.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to confirm.